# building a matrix composed of alternative object in python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, numpy

I'm fairly new to python and I am currently making use of the numPy library along with pyinterval library. I want to build a matrix that isn't composed of floats, but intervals.

however if I do the following:

```
A = [[interval([2,3]), interval([0,1]), interval([1,2]), interval([2,3])]]
m = np.matrix(A,interval)
```

it gives the following error:

```
raise ValueError, "matrix must be 2-dimensional"
```

In order to see how it was doing it I looked at this:

```
np.array(A)
```

and got the following output:

```
array([[[[ 2.,  3.]],
    [[ 0.,  1.]],
    [[ 1.,  2.]],
    [[ 2.,  3.]]]])
```

when I wanted to see something like:

```
array([[interval(2,3), interval[0,1],
       [interval(1,2), interval[2,3]])
```

I'm not sure how to get it to understand the type that I am using, I have tried various things after doing some searches but nothing seems to work.

How can I get it to see one interval as only one element in the array/matrix?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the docs regarding dtype syntax](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html#defining-structured-arrays):

> each type specifier can be prefixed with a repetition number, or a
>   shape. In these cases an array element is created, i.e., an array
>   within a record. That array is still referred to as a single field.

So to specify it as one item in the array, you might try setting the dtype to `'(2,)object'`:

To make a 2x2 ndarray:

```
import interval
A = [(interval.interval([2,3]), interval.interval([0,1])),
     (interval.interval([1,2]), interval.interval([2,3]))]
a = np.array(A,dtype='(2,)object')
```

To make a 2x2 matrix:

```
m=np.matrix(A,dtype='(2,)object')
```

Warning: I don't really understand dtype syntax. It is far too complicated and occasionally I see strange bug reports ([#1955](http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/ticket/1955),[#1760](http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/ticket/1760), [#1580](http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/ticket/1580)) related to use of exotic dtypes. My personal conclusion is that it is safer to stick to plain, simple dtypes. Or, if you need to use a more complicated dtype, unit test it to make sure it behaves as you expect.

---

**An easier, better way** to define the arrays is:

```
A = [(interval.interval([2,3]), interval.interval([0,1])),
     (interval.interval([1,2]), interval.interval([2,3]))]
a = np.empty((2,2),dtype='object')
a[:]=A
```

This tells numpy explicity what shape array you want, and then, since the dtype is `object`, you can stuff whatever you please into the cells of the array.

Moreover, unlike the `dtype='(2,)object'` solution above, it also works for 1D arrays:

```
bd = [interval.interval([0,1]),
      interval.interval([6,7])]

b = np.empty(2,dtype='object')
b[:]=bd
```

Comment: it still acts a little strangely: If i have the following code:
bd = [interval([0,1]), interval([6,7])]
b = np.array(bd,dtype='(2,)object')
i get:
array([[(0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0)],
[(6.0, 7.0), (6.0, 7.0)]], dtype=object)
rather than
array([[interval(0.0, 1.0)],
       [(6.0, 7.0)]], dtype=object)

do you know why this is?

Comment: Good point. It finally dawned on me there is an easier way to define the arrays without messing with `dtype`. I've edited the post to show what I mean.